# How to check if 2 or more queries are executing respectively and in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have two procedures that run smoothly named `update_students` and `insert_payment`.

```
Sub insert_payment() 

con.open
Using cmd as New MySQLCommand  
  With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandType = CommanType.Text
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblpayment(stud_id,payment_amount) VALUES (@stud_id,@payment_amount);"
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@stud_id", txtid.text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_amount", txtpay.text)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
con.Close()
End Using

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub update_students() 

con.open
Using cmd as New MySQLCommand  
  With cmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandType = CommanType.Text
    .CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_stud SET tuition_status=@tuition_status,address_school=@address_school;"
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtid.text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuition_status", txtns.text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_school", txtadd.text)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
con.Close()
End Using

End Sub
```

then now in my Add button click event, I called both of the procedures to execute. Although I don't encounter errors.

My problem is I want to know if both procedures are completely executed at the same time. If 1st or 2nd or both of them encountered an error it should notify then both INSERT and UPDATE will not be executed.

I'm doing this because I want to add/update two tables by Inserting and updating them synchronously.

Sorry for my bad English. I hope someone here can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just saying that you don't want to do the update if the insert fails?

Comment: exactly sir and vice versa.

Comment: Create a stored procedure that performs both requests and rollbacks if one or both of them result in an error. Call it in one subroutine transferring all 4 parameters into it.

Comment: You can create a stored procedure if you want but there's no need. Just look into using transactions with ADO.NET. You begin a transaction and execute both commands within it. If both succeed then you commit and if either fails you rollback. No, I'm not going to show you how to do it. Now that you know the topic to research, you can research it and try to implement it yourself. If what you try fails, then you can ask a new question about that.

Comment: ok sir i will try your suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I made and it's working.

I'm afraid if this code isn't clean and ok to use. Any suggestion?

```
Public Sub bTrans()
        
        con.Open()
        Dim trans As MySqlTransaction
        trans = con.BeginTransaction()
        Try
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblinventory (itemcode,stocks,unit,unitprice,supplierprice,additional,postingdate) values (@itemcode,@stocks,@unit,@unitprice,@supplierprice,@additional,@postingdate);"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtCode.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@stocks", txtNew.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", cbUnit.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitprice", txtTotalPrice.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierprice", txtOld.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@additional", txtAddition.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@postingdate", Now())
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            End Using
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .Transaction = trans
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE tblMedicine SET AddedStocks=@AddedStocks where ItemCode=@ItemCode ;"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", txtCode.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddedStocks", 1)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            End Using
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblstocktransaction (itemcode,acquiredate,quantity,unit,unitprice,expirydate,supplier,postingdate,supplierprice,additionalprice) values (@itemcode,@acquiredate,@quantity,@unit,@unitprice,@expirydate,@supplier,@postingdate,@supplierprice,@additionalprice);"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemcode", txtCode.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@acquiredate", dtAcq.Value)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", txtNew.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", cbUnit.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitprice", txtTotalPrice.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@expirydate", dtExp.Value)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier", cbSupplier.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@postingdate", dtPost.Value)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierprice", txtOld.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@additionalprice", txtAddition.Text)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            End Using
            trans.Commit()
            MsgBox("Succcessfully added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pharmacy Inventory and Management System")

        Catch e As Exception
            Try
                trans.Rollback()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                If Not trans.Connection Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox("Transaction failed due to wrong entry! Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pharmacy Inventory and Management System")
                End If
            End Try
            MsgBox("Transaction failed due to wrong entry! Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Pharmacy Inventory and Management System")
        Finally
            con.Close()
            trans.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
```